#  to pass a command in a  file?

Tags: php, variables, httpserver

I want to run a executable file from my php script and the command used in the command line is
where, profit is the executable file and profit.in is the input file. I wrote the following php script for running  The same program when ran in the command prompt

Comment: try it with `system` function

Comment: Where is your profit.in file? when your PHP script is running are you sure the profit.in file is in the same directory your php script thinks its running from?

Comment: @BugFinder yes i looked at that long before... both profit.in and the php script is in same folder

Comment: and you're running php from the command line?

Comment: @BugFinder no i m running the program using browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec doesn't return the result to `$profit`, try it this way:

```
exec('C:/xampp/htdocs/example/profit.exe < profit.in',$results,$status);
if ($status === 0)
{
    var_dump($results);//will be an array
}
```

Also make sure that the path to your parameter file is correct, best use an absolute path if it's not being generated by your script.

*Notes*
Since your `exec` calls leads me to believe you're working on a windows box, the path separator is a **backslash**, which you should escape, too:

```
exec('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\example\\profit.exe < profit.in',$results,$status);
```

is what it should look like, imo.

A second possible issue just came to mind: you're using xampp, on a windows machine. If you're running this script from the command line, make sure you're using the right exe: `php-cli.exe`, instead of the `php.exe`:

Comment: Thanls @Elias :) but the output prints as a array... how can i remove the array and print the normal output as a string?

Comment: Any way you like, it's just an array like any other. If you need it printed out in your console/ command prompt: `echo implode('"\n",$results);` Here, double quotes are important, when using single quotes `\n` will be treated as a string, not a line feed. 
You could also loop through the array (`while($line = array_shift($results))` or `for ($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++)`) and treat each line of output as you please... go mad!:)
Oh, yes a windows linefeed isn't `\n`, but `\r\n`, so use the appropriate line terminator

Comment: Glad to help, just noticed your comment, if you're running this script on a browser, try this with the results array: `echo implode('<br/>',$results);`